# Why my Object ArrayList loop result is incorrect?

Tags: java

I create a Object Arraylist of CompanyRecord and insert value in it. But when I loop the data is wrong.

```
public class CompanyRecord {
private String Code;
private String Name;
public void setValue(String value1,String column1)
{
    if (column1.equals("Code"))
    {
        this.Code=value1;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.Name=value1;
    }
}

public String getValue(String column1)
{

    if (column1.equals("Code"))
    {
        return Code;
    }
    else 
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

}
```

The loop and insert code is:

```
ArrayList<CompanyRecord> codelist=new ArrayList<CompanyRecord>();
CompanyRecord codeItem=new CompanyRecord();
codeItem.setValue("first", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("1", "Name");
odelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem.setValue("second", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("2", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem.setValue("third", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("3", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

for (int j=0;j<codelist.size();j++)
    {
        System.out.println(codelist.get(j).getValue("Code")+'\t'+codelist.get(j).getValue("Name"));
    }
```

I think the result should be first 1, second 2, thrid 3. But instead it's three lines of third 3.
What's the issue? I'm really confused. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: don't change the values of the original codeItem, create a new one each time you want to add it to your list. In your list, you only store a reference to your object, and since you overwrite the values in that object, it's normal you get the last set values

Comment: you created only one instance of record, and just set/changed its field each time - you musts create one instance **for each record** (before setting fields) - Adding an instance of the list does not create a copy (or create a new one) (in technical words, it is adding a reference, a pointer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<CompanyRecord> codelist=new ArrayList<CompanyRecord>();
CompanyRecord codeItem=new CompanyRecord();
codeItem.setValue("first", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("1", "Name");
odelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem.setValue("second", "Code"); #Overwritten existing object
codeItem.setValue("2", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem.setValue("third", "Code"); #Overwritten existing object
codeItem.setValue("3", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

for (int j=0;j<codelist.size();j++)
    {
        System.out.println(codelist.get(j).getValue("Code")+'\t'+codelist.get(j).getValue("Name"));
    }
```

Its a mistake in your code. You are overwriting the same object with new values. You have to create a new `CompanyRecord` object for each `.add()` call of the list. Adding to a list does not remove the reference, what ever change you do on an object, it will reflect.

It must be like

```
CompanyRecord codeItem=new CompanyRecord();
codeItem.setValue("first", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("1", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem=new CompanyRecord(); #create new object
codeItem.setValue("second", "Code"); 
codeItem.setValue("2", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);
......
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a new Object for each

```
CompanyRecord codeItem=new CompanyRecord(); 
codeItem.setValue("first", "Code"); codeItem.setValue("1", "Name");   
codelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem=new CompanyRecord(); 
codeItem.setValue("second", "Code"); codeItem.setValue("2", "Name");   
codelist.add(codeItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `new` object.

```
List<CompanyRecord> codelist = new ArrayList<CompanyRecord>();
    CompanyRecord codeItem = new CompanyRecord();
    codeItem.setValue("first", "Code");
    codeItem.setValue("1", "Name");
    codelist.add(codeItem);

    codeItem = new CompanyRecord();
    codeItem.setValue("second", "Code");
    codeItem.setValue("2", "Name");
    codelist.add(codeItem);

    codeItem = new CompanyRecord();
    codeItem.setValue("third", "Code");
    codeItem.setValue("3", "Name");
    codelist.add(codeItem);

    codelist.forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getValue("Name"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to create new instance for getting different object from the list.

```
CompanyRecord codeItem=new CompanyRecord();
codeItem.setValue("first", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("1", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem.setValue("second", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("2", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem.setValue("third", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("3", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);
```

Here we use the same reference and setting its value three times, due to which the final value is the latest assignment.

Assign new object

```
CompanyRecord codeItem=new CompanyRecord();
codeItem.setValue("first", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("1", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem=new CompanyRecord();
codeItem.setValue("second", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("2", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);

codeItem=new CompanyRecord();
codeItem.setValue("third", "Code");
codeItem.setValue("3", "Name");
codelist.add(codeItem);
```